# Configuring auto_escape in freemarker spring-mvc Application

Tags: spring, freemarker

I am using spring-mvc with `freemarker-2.3.27-incubating.jar`.
And bean configuration for view-resolver like below...

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/"/>
    <property name="freemarkerSettings">
        <props>
            <prop key="template_exception_handler">rethrow</prop>
            <prop key="number_format">0.########</prop>
            <prop key="date_format">dd/MM/yyyy</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
    <property name="exposeRequestAttributes" value="true"/>
    <property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true"/>
    <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="rc"/>
</bean>
```

Where and how can I use `<#ftl output_format="HTML">` or `<#ftl output_format="HTML" auto_esc=true>` to enable `HTML auto-scape` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#ftl` tags you just add at the beginning of the template files themselves. But I would recommend setting `recognize_standard_file_extensions` to `true` in the `freemarkerSettings` properties, and then use `.ftlh` file extension instead of `.ftl`. Or, even better, you set `incompatible_improvements` to `2.3.27` there instead, which enables `recognize_standard_file_extensions` and some fixes. (Last not least, in case you want this for `.ftl` for some reason, you can set `output_format` to `HTMLOutputFormat` in `freemarkerSettings` properties too.)

Comment: is this means `<!--<prop key="recognize_standard_file_extensions">true</prop>-->
                <prop key="incompatible_improvements">2.3.27</prop>
                <prop key="output_format">HTML</prop>` . But this wont work

Comment: Yes. (Without commenting it out, of course.) What doesn't work?

Comment: Without comment of these three prop, the project reconstruct again and again not run finally. When I tried without `output_format` then the project run but `${.output_format}` prints `undefined` and `${.auto_esc?c}` prints `false`.

Comment: Well, if you comment them out, then of course `${.output_format}` will be `undefined`, etc. Why does the project get into that loop is the thing to investigate here. Is there some error in the log? Maybe the service was set to restart after terminating with error, and it always terminates with error as you are using an old FreeMarker version (due to some classpath mess) that doesn't yet support these settings. Check what `${.version}` prints.

Comment: `${.version}` prints `2.3.27-incubating`. Error log for setting up output formats for `HTML` like these...`Caused by: freemarker.core.Configurable$SettingValueAssignmentException: Failed to set FreeMarker configuration setting "output_format" to value "HTML"; see cause exception.
  at freemarker.core.Configurable.settingValueAssignmentException(Configurable.java:2818)` AND `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HTML
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
  at freemarker.template.utility.ClassUtil.forName(ClassUtil.java:88)`

Comment: Ah... sorry, the setting value should be `HTMLOutputFormat` (the class name), not `HTML`. I have fixed it in my answer. (But simply using `.ftlh` file extension is still recommended over setting the `output_format` on the Configuration level.)

Comment: Yes, that the point. Now `${.output_format}` prints **HTML** and `${.auto_esc?c}` prints **true**. But `<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring/>` shows an error `Using ?html (legacy escaping) is not allowed when auto-escaping is on with a markup output format (HTML), to avoid double-escaping mistakes.`

Comment: Using HTML auto-escaping for `.ftlh` files only (as recommended in the documentation) avoids such problems with legacy templates. But if you must stick to the `ftl` file extension, you can use the `templateConfigurations` setting (see https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_templateconfigurations.html) to set different output formats (like `UndefinedOutputFormat`) for different templates.